# When trying to have a div overlay contents below it, it doesn't overlay, just pushes content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue of overlaying a hidden div, when I click a button. What I am trying to have happen is when the hidden div appears that it goes on top of everything else below it based on its height. All I can get it to do is push everything else downwards as you can see in my snippet.

Other solutions that I have looked at haven't taken in consideration of using bootstrap, and when I am testing out the solutions I have found, it puts everything out of whack, and that would be when I use absolute as position, like the solutions I have seen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#myHiddenDiv").hide();

});

$("#myBtn").click(function () {
  $("#myHiddenDiv").toggle();
});

$("#btn2").click(function () {
  $("#myHiddenDiv").toggle();
});
```

```css
#myHiddenDiv {
    /*width: 325px;*/
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row row-splitter">
                <label for="ddLocation" class="col-md-1 control-label">Location</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   
                    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">Click Me</div>
                </div>
                <div id="myHiddenDiv" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10" style="z-index:2; position:relative">
                    <div id="MaterialGridList">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="z-index:1; position:relative;">
                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <label for="ddLocationMaterial" class="col-md-1 control-label">Material</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location Material.." />
                    </div>

                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Color</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" id="ddColor" class="form-control" style="width:100%" />
                    </div>

                    <label for="qty" class="col-md-1 control-label">Length</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Length..." />
                    </div>

                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="text" id="qty2" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width in Inches</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div style="border:1px solid black; height:400px; border-radius:5px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You will need to add `position` to your hidden div if you want it to appear "above" the normal content flow, rather than right in the middle of it.

Comment: I tried using position of absolute earlier but when it came to setting the top,left,right and bottom, it didn't work out properly and since i am using bootstrap i need to keep the respnsive aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `position: absolute`. To fix the whackiness, just add the line `width: 100%` to `#myHiddenDiv`.

I would also suggest taking a look at jQuery animation methods, like `.fadeToggle()` and `.slideToggle()`.

Below's the working sample.

EDIT: Rewrote some code to address issues pointed on comments

```js
$("#myBtn, #btn2").click(function () {
  $("#myHiddenDiv").toggle();
});
```

```css
#myHiddenDiv {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 2;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#ddColor  {
    width: 100%;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.black-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row row-splitter">
                <label for="ddLocation" class="col-md-1 control-label">Location</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   
                    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">Click Me</div>
                </div>
                <div id="myHiddenDiv" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    <div id="MaterialGridList">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative">
                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <label for="ddLocationMaterial" class="col-md-1 control-label">Material</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location Material.." />
                    </div>

                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Color</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" id="ddColor" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <label for="qty" class="col-md-1 control-label">Length</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Length..." />
                    </div>

                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="text" id="qty2" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width in Inches</label>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row row-splitter">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div class="black-border"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should add CSS to the existing external CSS section rather than inline; that's dangerous practice.

Comment: Did not add, only change. I agree, CSS should be inside <style> elements.

Comment: I'll be adding the css to an external file. I agree 100% that css should be in an external file, same with Javascript / JQuery

Comment: @rabello Well, CSS should be inside CSS files rather than inside `<style>` elements in the `<head>` of an HTML document. Separation of concerns and all that.

Comment: Ultimately it will end up there. I simplified my comment. I agree on separate files as well

Comment: @TylerH There, rewrote the code to be as real-life and best-practice as possible on a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring some stuf, this could work for you. You need to use the atribute "position" with "absolute" value for box and the form need to have "relative" value. Use the z-index attribute to set the position versus other tags.

```js
$(function () {

     $("#myBtn").click(function () {
         $("#myHiddenDiv").toggle();
     });

});
```

```css
.form-container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 8;
}

#myHiddenDiv {
    display: none;
    height: 100%; 
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="row row-splitter">
                 <label for="ddLocation" class="col-md-1 control-label">Location</label>
                 <div class="col-md-2"> 
                     <div class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">Click Me</div>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-container">
                 <div id="myHiddenDiv" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                     <div id="MaterialGridList"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row row-splitter">
                     <label for="ddLocationMaterial" class="col-md-1 control-label">Material</label>
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location Material.." />
                     </div>

                     <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Color</label>
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <input type="text" id="ddColor" class="form-control" style="width:100%" />
                     </div>

                     <label for="qty" class="col-md-1 control-label">Length</label>
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Length..." />
                     </div>

                     <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width</label>
                     <div class="col-md-1">
                         <input type="text" id="qty2" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                     </div>

                 </div>

                 <div class="row row-splitter">
                     <label for="ddColor" class="col-md-1 control-label">Width in Inches</label>
                     <div class="col-md-1">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Width..." />
                     </div>

                 </div>
                 <div class="row row-splitter">
                     <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                         <div style="border:1px solid black; height:400px; border-radius:5px;"></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </body>
```